# How do you format the exposed filter options?

Tags: views

I am guessing this is a easy question, but I am stumped for a couple of hours.
I am using Views with some exposed filters as shown below.

- Search keyword
- Drawing Type
- Type of Mould
- Customer Name

  [image: screenshot]

They are all in one line where "Customer Name" and the "apply" button are wrapped onto the next line.
How do I make "Search keywords" in one line, then "Drawing Type" + "Type of Mould" + "Customer Name" on another line, and "Apply" button alone on the last line?

Comment: I cleared the cache as suggested above but still no change in formatting. My view is called "drawingsearch" and when I look under the tab theme -> information, I do not see the file views-exposed-form.tpl.php being accessed anywhere there. I would assume it should be listed there somewhere ... maybe under "display output"?

Answer (score 5):

Views 3 for Drupal 7 kindly gives each exposed widget DIV a class with a unique name. Then it's a matter of adding clear and float attributes.

If you're using Views 2 you will have to override the views-exposed-form.tpl.php file in the views/theme folder. You can just copy and save this code in a file called views-exposed-form.tpl.php in your theme file path. It should override the original template file.

```
<?php
// $Id: views-exposed-form.tpl.php,v 1.4.4.1 2009/11/18 20:37:58 merlinofchaos Exp $
/**
 * @file views-exposed-form.tpl.php
 *
 * This template handles the layout of the views exposed filter form.
 *
 * Variables available:
 * - $widgets: An array of exposed form widgets. Each widget contains:
 * - $widget->label: The visible label to print. May be optional.
 * - $widget->operator: The operator for the widget. May be optional.
 * - $widget->widget: The widget itself.
 * - $button: The submit button for the form.
 *
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */
?>
<?php if (!empty($q)): ?>
  <?php
    // This ensures that, if clean URLs are off, the 'q' is added first so that
    // it shows up first in the URL.
    print $q;
  ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="views-exposed-form">
  <div class="views-exposed-widgets clear-block">
    <?php foreach($widgets as $id => $widget): ?>
      <div class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-<?php print $id ?>">
        <?php if (!empty($widget->label)): ?>
          <label for="<?php print $widget->id; ?>">
            <?php print $widget->label; ?>
          </label>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (!empty($widget->operator)): ?>
          <div class="views-operator">
            <?php print $widget->operator; ?>
          </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="views-widget">
          <?php print $widget->widget; ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <div class="views-exposed-widget">
      <?php print $button ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Adam S for the reply. I tried your suggestion but did not see any changes. I am using Drupal 6.x and Views 2.3. I replaced my existing views-exposed-form.tpl.php file with your updated code above. In views I went to information - rescan template files. Nothing changed. As added measure I restarted the drupal server and still no change. Am I missing or doing something wrong?

Comment: I just tested it and it works great. Make sure to clear the cache not restart the Drupal server. It's under admin/settings/performance . Also, you can wrap the div in markup if you need to for the image.

Comment: A slight correction on endless summer's post: That should be `<div class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-<?php print $widget->id ?>">`. (Note the use of `$widget->id` rather than `$id`.)

Answer (score 0):

After saving the above code as a template override in my theme folder I modified  it to ensure all form elements and their "wrapper" DIVs have unique id="" attributes.

In my case, I was outputting the same view twice on a page. One Mobile (field list) version and one Desktop (table) (for responsive website layout). The original code didn't pass Web Accessibility Standards (Double A) - yaaawn!!

```
foreach ($widgets as $id => $widget):
  $id_attr = drupal_html_id($widget->id);
  ?>
  <div id="<?php print $id_attr; ?>-wrapper" class="views-exposed-widget views-widget-<?php print $id; ?>">
    <?php if (!empty($widget->label)): ?>
      <label for="<?php print $id_attr; ?>">
```