# How to override the widget of an exposed form filter?

Tags: 7, views, theming, entities

I have a view with a single filter criteria (let's call it *category*) exposed to the user. The user can also select multiple *categories* in for this view (standard view stuff).

The *category* selection filter is rendered to the user in a big `<select>` for element. **For aesthetic reasons, this is undesirable**.

What I'm trying to do is override the display of the widget that renders out the `<select>` element. I've copied my `/sites/all/modules/view/themes/views-exposed-form.php.tpl` to my theme's folder, however, the widget itself (which contains the `<select>` form control I want to change to something else) is simply rendered by `$widget->widget;`

How can I change how the widget renders the multiple *categories* selection filter in the view?

**Edit**, for more info and clarity: [This question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2961/how-do-you-format-the-exposed-filter-options) deals with styling a widget, which is not quite what I want to do. I want to change the markup that renders the widget.

**Another edit (after answering my own question):** Turns out *widget* is not quite the correct Drupal terminology to use here for the exposed form filter.

Comment: What changes are you trying to make to it?  You don't want it to be a select element or you're just trying to change its size (something css could do) or?

Comment: I'm essentially trying to change the select element to a css-styled tabs or checkboxes, or anything that's not locked into that <select> form element

Answer (score 7):

Ok, so after spending a day digging around the net, it seems that there are two ways to do this.

First off, for clarification, the exposed filter from the view **is not a widget**, at least in the Drupal sense of the word. In the traditional Drupal sense of the word, a widget is something used on an **edit** form or **add** form. Hooks like `hook_field_widget_alter()` and it's brethren operate on these widgets.

Just because the `views-exposed-form.php.tpl` has `$widget` as a variable, THAT DOES NOT MAKE IT A WIDGET!!!

Now that that confusion is out of the way, there are two ways to change the exposed filter.

1. Add a custom module and use `hook_form_alter` to change things about the exposed filter form. I got as far as creating a custom module (called *bypass*) and creating a hook to display some simple debugging info:

   ```
   function bypass_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
       dsm($form_id);
       dsm($form);
   }
   ```

when I discovered the [Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module.

2. Use the Better Exposed Filters module to display the filters as checkboxes, radio buttons, etc. and style those.

Option 2 is what I'm doing now.  Hope this helps someone :)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the widget thing, it was very helpful.

Comment: You don't need to create special module to use `hook_form_alter()` just use `template.php` in your theme https://www.drupal.org/node/1418546#comment-5522050